# C++ to compare 2 lists of strings

Tags: c++, performance, string-matching, set-intersection

In Python, set is pretty handy for comparing 2 lists of strings (see this [link](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/compare-2-lists-for-same-words-certain-strings-765278.html)). I was wondering if there's a good solution for C++ in terms of performance. As each list has over 1 million strings in it.

It's case-sensitive matching.

Comment: Use the C++ analogue of a Python set: std::set<std::string>

Comment: The lists are not sorted. And the goal is to find matching strings in both lists (intersection).

Comment: Do you need all the words? Or just a few, e.g. 10 starting from `biscuit`?

Comment: All the words, it has to be exactly matching.

Comment: I mean, do you need to process all 1 million and have them available, or just some slice, like a screen showing 20 alphabetical matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data types `std::set<>` (usually implemented as a balanced tree) and `std::unordered_set<>` (from C++11, implemented as a hash) are available. There is also a convenience algorithm called `std::set_intersection` that computes the actual intersection.

Here is an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>             // for std::set
#include <algorithm>       // for std::set_intersection

int main()
{
  std::set<std::string> s1 { "red", "green", "blue" };
  std::set<std::string> s2 { "black", "blue", "white", "green" };

  /* Collecting the results in a vector. The vector may grow quite
     large -- it may be more efficient to print the elements directly. */     
  std::vector<std::string> s_both {};

  std::set_intersection(s1.begin(),s1.end(),
                        s2.begin(),s2.end(),
                        std::back_inserter(s_both));

  /* Printing the elements collected by the vector, just to show that
     the result is correct. */
  for (const std::string &s : s_both)
    std::cout << s << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Note. If you want to use `std::unordered_set<>`, the `std::set_intersection` cannot be used like this, because it expects the input sets to be ordered. You'd have to use the usual technique of a for-loop iterating over the smaller set and finding the elements in the larger one to determine the intersection. Nevertheless, for a large number of elements (especially, strings), the hash-based `std::unordered_set<>` may be faster. There are also STL-compatible implementations such as the one in Boost ([`boost::unordered_set`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_set.html)) and the one created by Google ([`sparse_hash_set` and `dense_hash_set`](http://code.google.com/p/sparsehash/)). For various other implementations and benchmarks (including one for strings), see [here](http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html).

Comment: "a for-loop iterating over the smaller set and finding the elements in the larger one" - that's assuming one set includes all the elements in the other... more typically you would want/need to mark/record elements seen then have a second loop through the other set.  Also worth noting that if the aim is to write the results out, then creating a temporary `s_both` set is wasteful of memory, but it's a nice illustration.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Yes, putting the results in a vector may be wasteful. I'll add a comment in the post that this is for illustration purposes. Note sure I understand the other comment. I assumed the goal is to find the intersection (i.e. elements both sets have in common), because that's what the Python script does the OP linked to. For set intersection it's sufficient to iterate through one list and search the other, even if the other is not a superset of the first. (Of course this assumes that searching the other list is efficient, which it is if the list is a hash-set).

Comment: @jogojapan: sorry mate - I just read "comparing" and didn't follow the link to see the Python was only an intersection (who wants to read Python? ;-P).  Fair point then, and a +1 from me.

Comment: Would it be even faster if looping the smaller list with multi-threading as both lists are static and won't be changed.

Comment: @Stan Yes, that's worth a try if the total number of elements justifies it. (Strictly speaking, even reading from a constant set is not officially thread-safe, but I'd say it should be fine.) If you collect the results in a vector (or similar), it's a good idea to maintain a separate results structure in each thread, and merge them after all threads have finished, to avoid having to use a lock when inserting result elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need much performance I suggest using map/set from STL:

```
list<string> list, list2;
...
set<string> sndList;
list<string> result;

for(list<string>::iterator it = list2.begin(); it != list2.end(); ++it)
   sndList.insert(*it);

for(list<string>::iteratir it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    if(sndList.count(*it) > 0)
        result.push_back(*it);
```

Otherwise I suggest some hashing function for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a `std::list` you have, sort them and use `set_intersection`:

```
list<string> words1;
list<string> words2;
list<string> common_words;

words1.sort();
words2.sort();

set_intersection(words1.begin(), words1.end(),
                 words2.begin(), words2.end(),
                 back_inserter(common_words));
```